# How to merge two file in R with the same column?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, match

I want to merge two file in R with the same column `ID` as below:

File1:

```
ID          feature1      feature2       feature3
A,B,C       1             100            150
D,F         2             200            500
G,R         2             200            600
H           6             500            800
S           8             600            700
```

File2:

```r
ID     feature4    feature5
A      5           4
F      6           7
G      4           3
H      8           2
P      2           1
```

OUTPUT:

```
  ID          feature1      feature2       feature3     ID     feature4    feature5
  A,B,C        1              100            150         A          5           4
  D,F          2              200            500         F          6           7
  G,R          2              200            600         G          4           3
  H            6              500            800         H          8           2
  S            8              600            700         *          *           *
  *            *               *             *           P          2           1
```

Comment: When you say merge two _files_ do you mean data frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fuzzyjoin` and customize a vectorized matching function (like `grepl` below) given two columns, returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` as to whether they are a match.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_full_join(df1, df2, by = "ID", match_fun = Vectorize(\(x, y) grepl(y, x)))

#    ID.x feature1 feature2 feature3 ID.y feature4 feature5
# 1 A,B,C        1      100      150    A        5        4
# 2   D,F        2      200      500    F        6        7
# 3   G,R        2      200      600    G        4        3
# 4     H        6      500      800    H        8        2
# 5     S        8      600      700 <NA>       NA       NA
# 6  <NA>       NA       NA       NA    P        2        1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` and `full_join`. Arranging to get the `NA`s last in case of duplicated `ID`s.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest

full_join(df1 %>% 
    mutate(ID_1 = strsplit(ID, ",")) %>% 
    unnest(ID_1), df2, c("ID_1" = "ID")) %>% 
  arrange(ID, feature4) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(ID) & is.na(feature4)))
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  ID    feature1 feature2 feature3 ID_1  feature4 feature5
  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>    <int>    <int>
1 A,B,C        1      100      150 A            5        4
2 D,F          2      200      500 F            6        7
3 G,R          2      200      600 G            4        3
4 H            6      500      800 H            8        2
5 S            8      600      700 S           NA       NA
6 NA          NA       NA       NA P            2        1
```

##### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A,B,C", "D,F", "G,R", "H", "S"), feature1 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 8L), feature2 = c(100L, 200L, 200L, 500L, 600L), 
    feature3 = c(150L, 500L, 600L, 800L, 700L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "F", "G", "H", "P"), feature4 = c(5L, 
6L, 4L, 8L, 2L), feature5 = c(4L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```